# GraphQL : Implementing windowed pagination for regular list

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

I'm trying to implement a windowed pagination using a "List". I don't need the cursor based solution with connections, because I need to show numbered pages to the user.

There are "User" and "Post" objects."User" has one-to-many relation to "Post".

Using graphql-js for schema,
here is my schema for userType and postType:

```
var userType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'User',
    fields: () => ({
        id: globalIdField('User'),
        posts: {
            type: new GraphQLList(postType),
            args: {
                page:{
                    type: GraphQLInt,
                    defaultValue: 0
                }
            },
            resolve: (_, args) => {
                //code to return relevant result set
            },
        },
        totalPosts:{
            type: GraphQLInt,
            resolve: () => {
                //code to return total count
             }
        },
    }),
    interfaces: [nodeInterface],
});


var postType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Post',
    fields: () => ({
        id: globalIdField('Post'),
        name: {type: GraphQLString},
        //other fields
    }),
    interfaces: [nodeInterface],
});
```

Please notice the "totalPosts" field in "userType". Since there is going to be other Lists for the user,with the same paging needs, I'm going to end up maintaining lot of "total{Type}" variables in the fragment. This can be solved if I can send the totalCount within the List result somehow.

https://github.com/facebook/graphql/issues/4  this issue talks about implementing a wrapper over the List to include the totalCount in the result set.

I tried creating a wrapper like this:

```
var postList = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'PostList',
    fields:()=>({
        count: {
            type: GraphQLInt,
            resolve: ()=>getPosts().length  //this is total count
        },
        edges: {
            type: new GraphQLList(postType),
            resolve: () => {
                return getPosts() ; // this is results for the page, though I don't know how to use 'page' argument here
            },
        }

    }),
    interfaces: [nodeInterface],
});
```

but how should I connect this to the `userType`'s `posts` field? And how can I use a 'page' argument on this wrapper, like I have in original userType?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how should I connect this to the userType's posts field? And how can I use a 'page' argument on this wrapper, like I have in original userType?

One simple way to implement what you're trying to do is to define a *dumb* wrapper type `postList` like this:

```
var postList = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'PostList',
    fields:()=>({
        count: { type: GraphQLInt },
        edges: { type: new GraphQLList(postType) }
        // Consider renaming 'edges'. In your case, it's a list, not a 
        // connection. So, it can cause confusion in the long run.
    }),
});
```

Then in the `userType` definition, add a field of that wrapper type and define its resolve function like below. As for argument `page`, just describe it while defining the field type `posts`.

```
posts: {
    type: postList,
    args: {
        page:{
            type: GraphQLInt,
            defaultValue: 0
        },
        ...otherArgs
    },
    resolve: async (_, {page, ...otherArgs}) => {
        // Get posts for the given page number.
        const posts = await db.getPosts(page);

        // Prepare a server-side object, which corresponds to GraphQL 
        // object type postList.
        const postListObj = {
            count: posts.length,
            edges: posts 
        };
        // Consider renaming 'edges'. In your case, it's a list, not a 
        // connection. So, it can cause confusion in the long run.
    },
},
```

Comment: Thanks! it worked. had to remove the interfaces: [nodeInterface], from postList wrapper

Comment: I'm glad you found it useful. I remove `interfaces` field from `postList` wrapper, based on your feedback. Thanks!